# Getting model value and generated ID from within simple_form custom input

Tags: simple-form

I'm trying to make a custom input type with simple_form that will implement combobox-type functionality using [jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)
. What I need to do is output a hidden field that will hold the ID of the value selected and a text field for the user to type in.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class ComboboxInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
    def input
        html = @builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
        id = '' #what?
        value = '' #what?
        return "#{html}<input class='combobox-entry' data-id-input='#{id}' value='#{value}'".html_safe
    end
end
```

I need to get the ID of the hidden field that simple_form is generating to place as an HTML attribute on the text entry to allow the JavaScript to "hook up" the two fields. I also need to get the value from the model to prepopulate the text input. How do I do this from within my custom input?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the id as well, but I did get the value:

`def input
  current_value = object.send("#{attribute_name}")
end`

I just found a hokey id workaround:

`html = @builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
id = html.scan(/id="([^"]*)"/).first.first.to_s`

I know it's a hack, but it does work.  Since we don't have access directly to this type of resolution, it is likely to keep working even if the underlying id creation code changes.